# SubDomain getting Internal server error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, internal-server-error, godaddy-api

i am new to laravel, i managed to deploy my laravel project on godaddy shared hosting, it works perfectly... but the domain doesnt work...

this is the nature of my routes/web.php

```
<?php


Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], function(){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

});

Route::group(['domain' => 'cars.example.com'], function(){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('cars');
    });

});
```

so, whenever i try accessing cars.example.com, it brings the error "500 internal server error"

guys i need your help on this one, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but I am not using godaddy.

```
// All subdomain routes
Route::group(['domain' => 'cars.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('cars');
    });
});

// All domain routes
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

If you want to get fancy you could do this.

```
// Captures all sub domains
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.{tld}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view($subdomain);
    });
});

// All domain routes
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @whoacowboy but its like i want to use one laravel project for both the domain and subdomain, so that in one Route::group, i define allthe routes for that domain, and the do that for the other subdomains too, so here cars is not a folder but rather a view

Comment: I am doing something similar. This uses one project for both domain and subdomains. See notes on answer.

Comment: its works perfectly for the example.com domain, even after changing to your code, thanks to that , but its still giving me the "500 internal server error for the subdomain" do you think its a problem with my .htaccess file?

Comment: Oh, i just changed my document root of my subdomain from public_html/cars  to just public_html/ and every thing works just fine. Thanks so much.

Comment: I would imagine it has to do with your server set up. If you remove your domain routes does cars.example.com go to your domain? If not it is an issue with your server set up.